# Flutter: Null check operator used on a null value with in_app_purchases

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-dependencies, flutter-in-app-purchase

My app was working fine on both iOS and Android but after updating to Flutter 2.10.0 I'm getting this issue:

```
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 8991): #0      Element.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3203:31)
E/flutter ( 8991): #1      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:341:17)
E/flutter ( 8991): #2      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:293:30)
E/flutter ( 8991): #3      Shop.getPastPurchases.<anonymous closure> (package:my_rents/services/shop.dart:123:20)
E/flutter ( 8991): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter ( 8991): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 8991): #6      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter ( 8991): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter ( 8991): #8      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter ( 8991): #9      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter ( 8991): #10     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter ( 8991): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
E/flutter ( 8991): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 8991): #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter ( 8991): #14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter ( 8991): #15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
E/flutter ( 8991): #16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 8991): #17     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter ( 8991): #18     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter ( 8991): #19     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 8991): #20     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

My implementation:

```
Future<List<PurchaseDetails>> getPastPurchases(BuildContext context) async {
    if (this.purchases.isEmpty) {
      final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
          inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;

      _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
        if (purchaseDetailsList.isEmpty) {
          Provider.of<AdState>(context, listen: false).toggleAds(context, true);
        } else {
          listenToPurchaseUpdated(context, purchaseDetailsList);
        }
      }, onDone: () {
        _subscription.cancel();
      }, onError: (error) {
      });

      await inAppPurchase.restorePurchases(); // If I comment this line everything works

    }
    return this.purchases;
  }
```

Again, I made no changes on my code, just updating Flutter

Comment: can u add that line where it;s come

Comment: it's added and commented